# How to preload / caching images

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page in my ionic app with a fullscreen background image on "ion-content" using css:

```
<ion-content 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + bgImageSrc + ')'}"
  class="fullScreenBackground">
```

Now I should preload/cache the image before the view is rendered, to make sure the background is here instantly.

Does anyone have a good solution for that?

Comment: Ionic does have built in functionality called LoadingController, check the docs. Then you just need to look up a snippet to preload an image in JavaScript.

Comment: @rtpHarry Thanks for the hint, it's working!

Comment: great, i posted it as the answer, if you want to upvote it? :) then it counts towards my ionic4 tag badge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic does have built in functionality called LoadingController, check the docs.

Then you just need to look up a snippet to preload an image in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for marking this as the answer, if it was helpful please consider upvoting as well. I hate having to ask for votes like this but StackOverflow doesn't count it towards my Ionic4 tag badge without an upvote, which is... annoying.